# Ember.js authentication with Azure mobile services and windows live account

Tags: javascript, authentication, azure, ember.js

I am trying to finish off an Ember.js app that I have hooked up to Azure Mobile Services. I have the WAMS stuff locked down to only those who have authenticated with a Windows Live account. I can get it to to pop open the authentication to windows live, but I am not seeing it actually authenticate to the service. I also need it to persist and only show items available to those who have authenticated as well.

I was using state-manager to change states, but I am not sure if this is the best path to go down. What is the best way to authenticate with ember.js while passing it to WAMS?

I was following this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2013/05/15/web-client-development-with-ember-js-and-windows-azure-mobile-services-part-4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When Ember was being built it was not catching the LoginStateManager and that is why it was not transitioning into isAuthenticated. I moved it into my controllers and it is now working properly.